# How to change a content o pararaph when selecting different radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to change the content of a

Paragraph

when selecting different radio buttons?? Jquery is welcome!!

I'm attaching my current code and a jSFiddle bellow. I want to change the paragraph inside .mstotal. You can change that to an ID if necessary.

HTML

```
    <label class="ms_price">1.99<span>/year</span><input name="membership-type" type="radio" value="1"/></label>
    <label class="ms_price">2.50<span>/year</span><input name="membership-type" type="radio" value="2"/></label>
    <label class="ms_price">3.00<span>/year</span><input name="membership-type" type="radio" value="3"/></label>
    <label class="ms_price">4.99<span>/year</span><input name="membership-type" type="radio" value="4"/></label>



    <div class="ms_total">
      <p>Membership A - 1 Year:<span>$1.99</span></p>
    </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[name='membership-type']").live("change", function(){
            if ($(this).val() == "1") {
                 $(".ms_total").text("<p>Membership A - 1 Year:<span>$1.99</span></p>");                  
            } else if ($(this).val() == "2") {
                 $(".ms_total").text("<p>Membership B - 1 Year:<span>$2.50</span></p>");                  
            } else if ($(this).val() == "3") {
                 $(".ms_total").text("<p>Membership C - 1 Year:<span>$3.00</span></p>");                  
            } else if ($(this).val() == "4") {
                 $(".ms_total").text("<p>Membership D - 1 Year:<span>$4.99</span></p>");                  
            }
        }); 
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vinicius5581/8wn27zej/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [.live()](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed) to register the event handlers which is [removed in jQuery 1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed), so use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Also use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to set the html content.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name='membership-type']").on("change", function(){
        if ($(this).val() == "1") {
            $(".ms_total").html("<p>Membership A - 1 Year:<span>$1.99</span></p>");                  
        } else if ($(this).val() == "2") {
            $(".ms_total").html("<p>Membership B - 1 Year:<span>$2.50</span></p>");                  
        } else if ($(this).val() == "3") {
            $(".ms_total").html("<p>Membership C - 1 Year:<span>$3.00</span></p>");                  
        } else if ($(this).val() == "4") {
            $(".ms_total").html("<p>Membership D - 1 Year:<span>$4.99</span></p>");                  
        }
    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="ms_price">1.99<span>/year</span><input name="membership-type" type="radio" value="1"/></label>
<label class="ms_price">2.50<span>/year</span><input name="membership-type" type="radio" value="2"/></label>
<label class="ms_price">3.00<span>/year</span><input name="membership-type" type="radio" value="3"/></label>
<label class="ms_price">4.99<span>/year</span><input name="membership-type" type="radio" value="4"/></label>



<div class="ms_total">
  <p>Membership A - 1 Year:<span>$1.99</span></p>
</div>
```

---

If you want to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), use `.on(event, selector, handler)` format like

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('change', "input[name='membership-type']", function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "1") {
            $(".ms_total").html("<p>Membership A - 1 Year:<span>$1.99</span></p>");
        } else if ($(this).val() == "2") {
            $(".ms_total").html("<p>Membership B - 1 Year:<span>$2.50</span></p>");
        } else if ($(this).val() == "3") {
            $(".ms_total").html("<p>Membership C - 1 Year:<span>$3.00</span></p>");
        } else if ($(this).val() == "4") {
            $(".ms_total").html("<p>Membership D - 1 Year:<span>$4.99</span></p>");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="ms_price">1.99<span>/year</span>
    <input name="membership-type" type="radio" value="1" />
</label>
<label class="ms_price">2.50<span>/year</span>
    <input name="membership-type" type="radio" value="2" />
</label>
<label class="ms_price">3.00<span>/year</span>
    <input name="membership-type" type="radio" value="3" />
</label>
<label class="ms_price">4.99<span>/year</span>
    <input name="membership-type" type="radio" value="4" />
</label>
<div class="ms_total">
    <p>Membership A - 1 Year:<span>$1.99</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

[1](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed): http://api.jquery.com/live/